# What is the best practice for joining tables , to use Join or to use condition in Where Clause in LINQ to EF

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework, linq

Following are the two Queries :

```
var q =
from c in categories
join p in products on c.Category equals p.Category 
select new { Category = c.Name, ProductName = p.Name};
var list =q.toList();
```

And

```
var q =
from c in categories
from p in products.Where(bb => bb.Category == c.Category) 
select new { Category = c.Name, ProductName = p.Name};
var list =q.toList();
```

Both these  queries produced the same result but which of them is efficient and best to Use ?

Answer (score 1):

The `Where` condition must find a matching result for ALL row combinations for both tables, while `Join` on the other side takes only the matching rows from the second table.